# Removing PHP extension and re-writing query string with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to restructure an existing website and, at the same time, re-write the URLs to a more user-friendly format. What I have now is `http://example.com/test_vars.php?test_var1=value1&test_var2=value2` and, ideally, what I would like is `http://example.com/test_vars/test_var1/value1/test_var2/value2`

Admittedly, I'm new to modifying htaccess files, however have done my research and tried out a few things. The closest I've come to what I'm looking for (admittedly is not that close), but I've enclosed the code below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1 [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.html
RewriteRule .* index.html
```

With this, I end up with a URL of `http://example.com/test_vars.php/test_var1/value1/test_var2/value2` however, none of the variables are being passed to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `test_vars.php`, you have to manually parse the parameters. The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will contain `/test_var1/value1/test_var2/value2`. Write a simple function to parse the string with `explode()`, for example.

And to have your URL without the ".php" extension, change this line

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1 [L]
```

To this:

```
RewriteRule ^test_vars test_vars.php
```

Now you have your pretty URL: http://example.com/test_vars/test_var1/value1/test_var2/value2

Comment: That would look after my variables, perfectly, however, I still have the .php extension on http://crapaudexhibition.com/test_vars.php/test_var1/value1/test_var2/value2 - any idea how I can get rid of that?

Comment: That's great, but is there a more generic statement for other pages (I was just using test_vars as a test); I need to use it on multiple pages and possibly future pages.

Comment: Actually you should redirect all request to more global script `index.php` instead of a single script `test_vars.php`. In `index.php` you will have `/test_vars/test_var1/value1/test_var2/value2` from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Parse the string to get the "test_vars" part, and the rest of the string as key=>value pairs. You can then `include_once "test_vars.php"`.